# POST request in Axios retuning 401 Unauthorised

Tags: vue.js, axios, nativescript

```
async create() {
  const data = {
    name: this.name
  };
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Accept: "application/json",
    Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}`
  };
  axios
    .post("URL", data, headers)
    .then(res => {
      console.log('SUCCESS');
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err.response));
}
```

The token from the login component. The token is loaded correctly as the POST request returns success when tried in Postman but the axios call returns

```
{ message: 'Unauthenticated.' },
  status: 401,
  statusText: 'Unauthorized'
```

Any pointers would be appreciated to identify the direction or root of this error.

Comment: Is it a CORS request? I suggest digging into the request details in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: You can have a really good example of what postman sends as a JavaScript code by clicking on "Code" on the postman's request window.
Hope this will help you - Otherwise it's a bit complicated to solve the problem.

Comment: May be you can try sending the same request to [PostMan Echo](https://docs.postman-echo.com/?version=latest), at least you would know whether your parameters are reaching properly, understand whether the issue is on client side or server.

Comment: are you sure that at the time of the call this.token is loaded correctly? try making a console.log or putting a breakpoint before making the call

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the headers to the axios incorrectly. Try this:

```
const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Accept: "application/json",
    Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}`
};

axios.post(URL, data, { headers })
```

That's why your `Authorization` header is not included in your request and the server returns 401.